# How to integrate Single Sign-On with multiple ADFS?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, single-sign-on, adfs

I have an application developed in ASP.NET MVC and SQL Server.

Application is developed in a way that it can be used by multiple clients with Form-based authentication. We have more than 20 clients using the same app, no client-specific hosting.

Clients are requesting us to implement Single Sign-On but these clients have multiple AD’s like client A has On-prem AD, client B has Azure AD, and so on...

1. Is this feasible to implement SSO with multiple ADs along with form-based auth on a web application
2. What would be an ideal solution for this scenario other than client-specific hosting

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, implement an IDP like identityserver4 (free) or a commercial offering like Auth0.

Both can authenticate against your DB.

Then federate with the multiple ADFS via Home Realm Discovery.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is time to move away from traditional form based authentication. To achieve SSO with multiple IDP with different protocols (ldap, ADFS , SAML, OIDC), you should think centralizing your authentication and authorization layer. You might try Auth0 who provides out of box support to connect to different IDP via different protocols. Identity Server is an open source project. However, it is your responsibility to maintain the server.